# Is it possible to create custom protocol behaviours in the Untiy Networking?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a multiplayer network game in Untiy. The thing is that all the network handling is made by the UnityEngine. The game world should be generated randomly by the game server. Is it possible to send this randomly generated map to all the clients? Or do I have to implement my separate network stuff to do this?

Comment: cant you just pass the seed around and use the same algorithm to create the world on the clients?

Comment: Sure but how can I send the seed to the clients with the unity networking?

Comment: try https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html ofc there are other options including using different networking solutions ...